# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' but can not find another

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

Ok so I created a form that has one field but multiple submit buttons.  Have the form correct, no problem there.  Have an issue writing the php code to perform an action depending on which button is pressed.  Keep getting a parse and syntax error.  I have tried different variations of using the if/else statements as well as isset.  Still no luck.  AND I don't see any extra } that Im aware of.

```
    <?php
if($_REQUEST['Gift'] == "Dish1")
{
  header("Location: url1".urlencode($_POST['uid']))
}

else if($_REQUEST['Gift'] == "Dish2")
{
  header("Location: url2".urlencode($_POST['uid']))
}

else if($_REQUEST['Gift'] == "Dish3")
{
  header("Location: url3".urlencode($_POST['uid']))

}
```

.....etc 
    ?>

It says the error is online 5.... not sure how they parse their lines as the actual url addresses are quite long themselves and none contain }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `;` at the end of your header statements.

The `}` is not expected because a `;` (or something else allowed there) is required first.

Comment: Ok that took care of that error thank you but now when the form submits it goes to the php file on the server and not the url specified in the php file.  Any clues on that

Comment: @ZxChefHenryMinos Hi, and welcome to SO! If you have another question, post it as another question. =)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have semicolons. Every statement in PHP must have ';' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop `;` after statements:

```
header("Location: url1".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
```